# parent physicsBody doesn't work

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a GameScene.sks and Player.sks. Player.sks stores player sprite, that consists of 3 parts (body, hand[child of body] and lantern[child of hand]). In the custom class of this scene I create playerTexture from image and set it as physics body.

```
let playerTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "player_outline")
parent!.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: playerTexture, size: playerTexture.size())
```

I add player scene reference to the Game Scene. And when I move player, physics body staying behind sprite and don't move at all. If I don't use 'parent!' it will work, but physics body will have offset.
But if I create physics body from the Scene Editor, it works! What's happening?

**Player.swift**

```
class PlayerNode: SKSpriteNode, EventListenerNode {
func didMoveToScene() {
    let playerTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "player_outline")
    parent!.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: playerTexture, size: playerTexture.size())

    parent!.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player
    parent!.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Wall
}
}
```

**GameScene.swift**

```
var player: PlayerNode!
player = childNode(withName: "//player") as! PlayerNode
```

**Player.swift**
Player's body called 'player', arm called 'lanternArm' and it is a child of 'player', lantern called 'lantern' and it is a child of 'lanternArm'.

Comment: Can you show your code where you create the `player` node? Is this the player sprite consisting of the body, the hand and the lantern?

Comment: In Game Scene:
var player: PlayerNode!
player = childNode(withName: "//player") as! PlayerNode

Comment: but the physics body you define is for the parent, not `player`. Or should this read `player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: playerTexture, size: playerTexture.size())`

Comment: I corrected my question. Maybe it will be more clearly.
I define `parent!.physicsBody....` 'cuz I want to attach physics body to the center of body i.e. `player` not to the whole compound sprite.

Comment: You are attaching the physicsBody to `player'`s parent, not `player` itself. Is that what you want to do? What is player's parent?

Comment: This approach using in the [link](https://store.raywenderlich.com/products/2d-apple-games-by-tutorials?_ga=2.20378492.575890254.1494601264-1850651599.1470605092). I want to attach physics body to the `player`. If I write `physicsBody` without `parent!` it will have offset ( [link](https://pp.userapi.com/c837235/v837235975/34f4a/f8HzLUSMbNs.jpg) ). How can I avoid this offset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this code:

```
> parent!.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: playerTexture, size:
> playerTexture.size())
```

You are defining the physicsBody of player's parent, not player itself. Is that what you want to do? What is player's parent?

> If I don't use 'parent!' it will work,

So you have this:

```
physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: playerTexture, size: playerTexture.size())
```

Now you are defining `player`s physics body.

> but physics body will have offset.

Check the `anchorPoint` of `player`. If it's (0, 0) that will give you an offset physicsBody.

Comment: Thanks for you help! It seems I understood. I changed `anchorPoint` but player sprite begin rotating unacceptable for me. I must create separate masks for `physicsBody`. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Unfortunately physicsbodies don't work nicely with SKSpriteNodes with non-standard anchor points. You can offset the physics body using the initialiser `SKPhysicsbody(rectangleOf: CGSize, center: CGPoint)` which might be of use.